Debian Bookworm touchpad not working
Touchpad seems configured, cat /proc/bus/input/devices:
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000a Version=0063
N: Name="TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=21
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3

cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

xinput list:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]

but the touchpad isn't functioning. (Both trackpoint and USB mouse work.) System details, lshw includes:
  vendor: LENOVO
  version: ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 12

*-core
   *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 165U
      version: 6.170.4

*-input:0
   product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
   physical id: 1
   logical name: input0
   logical name: /dev/input/event0
   logical name: input0::capslock
   logical name: input0::numlock
   logical name: input0::scrolllock
   capabilities: i8042

*-input:5
   product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
   physical id: 6
   logical name: input14
   logical name: /dev/input/event13

*-input:7
   product: TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint
   physical id: 9
   logical name: input3
   logical name: /dev/input/event4
   logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
   capabilities: i8042

And lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7d02 (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P [Intel Graphics] (rev 08)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d03 (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e4d (rev 20)
00:06.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7eca (rev 10)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4     PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 7e4c (rev 20)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 7d0d (rev 01)
00:0b.0 Processing accelerators: Intel Corporation Device 7d1d (rev 04)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7e7f (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e40 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e70 (rev 20)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 7e73 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e38 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7e03 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P SPI Controller (rev 20)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Shenzhen Unionmemory Information System Ltd. Device 6a04 (rev 03)


Do you happen to have a dual-boot system (Windows) or a LiveCD/USB?  Does the touchpad function in the LiveOS/Window.  If it does work in another OS, we've ruled out a hardware failure.

@eyoung100 I don't immediately have that option available, unfortunately. My best guess: It's a new laptop, the touchpad isn't supported.

In that case do you mind providing a link to the laptop by including it in your question along with the relevant sections of a tool like lshw or lspci?

I've added what seems relevant from the former (output is long), and entire of latter.

I looked up i8042 at Linus Torvald's Github Kernel Repository, which means that trackpad is only being detected as a plain mouse.  It may still be supported, but we need to load the proper kernel module or driver for that. Searching for your device yielded this post over at AskUbuntu.  Let us know if that solves it.  Here's the relevant package

@eyoung100 that post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241907/tpps-2-elan-trackpoint-on-thinkpad-t495-with-kubuntu-20-04) is on the trackpoint, rather than touchpad

Please post the relevant bits for input0 and input5   I erroneously looked up input7.

@eyoung100, my mistake, added. I'm wondering whether the touchpad hardware is actually detected. "The following command will tell you whether you have a Synaptics, ALPS or Elantech touchpad: egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices" (https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad) which returns TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint, not a touchpad? But, maybe they'll both handled together.

After reading the link you posted, all devices in that grep are supported as Synaptics devices.  Read the Manual system-wide configuration to see if you can get it going.
